# IE 6 ajax post sending requestContent of undefined

Tags: ajax, spring, internet-explorer-6

I have this line of code in my Spring MVC 3.1 controller POST action

```
String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8));
```

When I log it, I see that the value is

> Attempting to parse content : undefined

The client that is posting to the website is IE 6 running on Windows CE.

I've attempted to replicate this on my desktop but the closest I can get is

> Attempting to parse content : "undefined"

The best I can guess it that IE 6 happily posts when `data : undefined`, but more modern browsers interpret that as no data.

Is this a known issue with IE 6?  Has anyone seen this problem before?  Is there an flag or something you can set on the Ajax request to disable this behavior?